# Recurrence Relation of An Algorithm

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

[image]

Question: Let $T(n)$ be the expected running time of find-index. Write a recurrence relation for T(n) and then solve it.

So random(n) takes constant time. The average running time should have a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of selecting the pivot. How do I write?

Comment: Depending perhaps on your model of computation, $random(n)$ can't really take constant time.  After all, its input and output have $\log_2 n$ bits, and it has to do **something** to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases. Either you find $k$ on the first try, or you don't.

- The first case happens with probability $1/n$. In that case, the algorithm runs for $1$ step.
- The second case happens with probability $1-1/n$. In that case, the algorithm runs for $1+T(n)$ steps on average. The $1$ is for the first check, while the $T(n)$ accounts for all subsequent checks.

Putting this all together,
$$
T(n) = \tfrac1n \cdot 1 + (1-\tfrac1n)\cdot (1+T(n))
$$
This recursivley expresses $T(n)$ in terms of itself.